# How to ignore folder modification time with rsync

Tags: rsync

When rsync compares src and dest trees, it checks for modification time. For folders, if the modification time changed, it'll update that modification in the destination. I'd prefer not. Ignoring the modification time of a folder doesn't mean ignoring the existence of that folder. The content will be compare and sync as usual. Only, the modification of the folder would not be updated.

Is there a way to ignore modification time, but ONLY for folder ?

Thanks.

Comment: There is not enough information to determine which command was used. It is possible to exclude specific folders. Consider using riff-backup if you need to restore only specific folders

Comment: I don't want to ignore specific folder. I just want to ignore the modification time for all folders when rsync is comparing source and dest trees.

Comment: please update the question, what do you really want to solve? for me looks similar like a [x-and-y problem](https://faq-database.de/doku.php?id=en:x-and-y-problem)

Comment: When rsync compares src and dest trees, it checks for modification time. For folders, if the modification time changed, it'll update that modification in the destination. I'd prefer not. Ignoring the modification time of a folder doesn't mean ignoring the existence of that folder. The content will be compare and sync as usual. Only, the modification of the folder would not be updated.
So is it possible to ignore modification time for folders ?

Comment: have you maybe considered `rsync --help |grep time | grep "\--"` for verification if your rsync implementation has `--ignore-times` or `--omit-dir-times` which might come maybe the nearest to your request?

Comment: --ignore-times wouldn't work because it also apply to files, but --omit-dir-times looks like exactly what I need.
Thanks.

Comment: let me know when it works so I can put it as an answer